# regular expression in getedit to remove numbers between brackets

Tags: regex, edit

I have a file with this format

```
cls>/opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1OutputPlatesReference/20150612_055948.932_0_Front.Frontview.png (79)
```

And I would like a regular expression to find all the numbers between brackets as when I write `[0-9]`, I get all the numbers in the file but I want to specify only the numbers between brackets

Comment: `[(](\d+)[)]`..like [this](https://regex101.com/r/dF1sJ9/1)

Comment: Thanks , now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\((\d+)\)
```

### Explanation:

Regex might confuse bracket as an expression, so you should escape it using `\`